# Visual Studio not showing server name when adding connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2012. When I try to connect to SQL Server through Visual Studio, I don't get my server name on Add connection drop down menu.

Comment: u need to add it yourself

Comment: If the DB is running on the localhost, just type the machine name

Comment: SQL server 2012 is running on your PC or different server?

Comment: add snapshot of connected to SQL SERVER Management Studio

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to SQL Server Management Studio to look for the correct `Server Name` and copy the value. Make all the configurations by yourself at the end just click `Test connection` button. If the connection is test successfully proceed with your work.

Comment: @mybirthname Does this look familiar, someone liked your answer enough to copy it word for word! http://stackoverflow.com/a/32823665/1663001

Answer (score 15):

If the database is in your local machine, Just put a . (Dot) in Server Name and select the database.

[image: Add connection dialogue]

Comment: This dot solution is great! Much easier then (local)/servername

Answer (score 4):

run services.msc
find " SQL server browser " , it might be disabled , start that service and set it to automatic.

Comment: This was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Insert machine_name/SqlServerName

Answer (score 0):

For people using sql server 2014+ and using the local db on your pc. simply set the server name to be (localdb)\ name of your database. It worked for me.