# sql server connection not showing up

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have mysql installed (including the connector for .net) and visual studio 2019 installed but when I try to connect via the one of the connections I have on the work bench by entering the name (it doesnt show up on the dropdown) I get the following error: server was not found or not accessible

[image: image of error]

here is the relevant server information

[image: relevant server info]

here a few other stack overflow related questions I found but none of them were helping me:

[Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-spec)

[SQL Server is not showing in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538511/sql-server-is-not-showing-in-visual-studio)

How do I ensure Remote connections are allowed?

Also I have visual studio 2019 which meant I couldn't download the special mysql toolbar but does that mean it won't work at all with visual studio 2019?

Comment: Maybe your sql server has specific port? If so then you need to specify it in connection like `localhost,1433\sql1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what ended up working is if I go back and install vs2017 as oppose to vs 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 pictures in your post, in the first you try to connect to **SQL Server**, not to **MySQL**.

Your second image says that `MySQL` connection was made.

So I imagine that you need to connect to `MySQL`, not to SQL Server, so you should not choose `Data Provider` for **SQL Server**, but any driver for **MySQL**

Comment: I don't follow. The second image was created by testing the connection from the mysql workbench. where do I edit those settings?

Comment: Your problem is that you think that MySql = SQL Server, but these are 2 distinct products. What you've installed is MySQL server, not SQL Server. On the second picture you've connected to your installed MySQL Server. In the first picture you are trying to connect to SQL Server that may not exist and in evrey case you don't need this server

Comment: right I had to install vs 2017 to use .net for mysql